# For $E=C([0,1])$ does $E\cong E\oplus E$ hold elementarily?

Tags: functional-analysis, exact-sequence

More precisely, I ask whether there is a "simple elementary" way to prove that there is a linear homeomorphism $E\to E\times E$ when for $I=[0,1]$ we have $E=C(I)$, the topological vector space of continuous functions $x:I\to\mathbb R$ topologized by the supremum norm. By "simple elementary" I refer to an argument which is approximatively "as simple" as the following allowing to prove $E\cong E\oplus F$ where $F=C_{\rm o}(I)$ is the subspace of $E$ formed by the functions $x$ with $x(0)=0$.

> **Argument.** Define $i_0:E\to E\times F$ by $z\mapsto(x,y)$ where $x(t)=z(\frac 12 t)$ and $y(t)=z(\frac 12(1+t))-z(\frac 12)$. It is trivial to check that $i_0$ is linear, continuous and bijective, and then the open mapping theorem implies that it is a linear homeomorphism.

The above argument in fact shows that there is a split short exact sequence of Banach(able topological vector) spaces:
$$
{\rm O}\longrightarrow E\overset i\longrightarrow 
                       E\overset p\longrightarrow F\longrightarrow{\rm O}
$$
where $i$ is defined by $(iu)(t)=u(2\,t)$ for $0\le t\le\frac 12$ and $(iu)(t)=u(1)$ for $\frac 12 < t\le 1$, and $p$ is defined by $(pv)(t)=v(\frac 12(1+t))-v(\frac 12)$ for $t\in I$. Then ${\rm Im\,}i={\rm Ker\,}p$, and we have the direct sum decomposition $E\cong E\oplus F$ since a topological linear complement of ${\rm Im\,}i$ in $E$ is the set of all $v$ in $E$ with $v(t)=0$ for $0\le t\le\frac 12$. I would like to have a split short exact sequence
$$
{\rm O}\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow 
                       E\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow{\rm O}
$$
by a "simple elementary" argument as above.

My basic motivation behind all this is that I would like to have a representation $C^\infty(\mathbb R)\cong(C^\infty(I))^{\kern.7mm\mathbb N_0}$ without using any sequence space representation of $C^\infty(I)$ by the space $s$ of rapidly decreasing sequences. I am just seaching for any ideas whether this is possible by first considering an overly simplified case.

Comment: But they can't be isomorphic because $E\oplus E$ has a non-trivial projection (onto one component), but $E$ does not. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Prahlad: In fact, $C[0,1]$ has lots of projections.

Comment: $C([0,1])\oplus C([0,1])\cong C([0,1]\cup[2,3])$. Using Milutin's theorem $C([0,1]\cup[2,3])\cong C([0,1])$. It is simple, but only with usage of sledgehammer.

Comment: I do not consider an application of Milutin's theorem as a "simple elementary argument". An argument I am after here should be such that it could somehow be relatively easily modified so as to be applicable to $C^\infty([0,1])$ instead of $C([0,1])$.

Comment: So what are you asking? Do you want an elementary proof of $E\oplus E\cong E$ for $E=C([0,1])$ or for $E=C^\infty([0,1])$?

Comment: Basically, as I shortly tried to explain it at the end of my question, I want it for $E=C^\infty([0,1])$ but I thought that it might be simpler if someone knew a "simple elementary" argument for $C([0,1])$ that could easily be modified so as to apply to $C^\infty([0,1])$. For example, it is well-known ($*$) that $C^\infty([0,1])$ is linearly homeomorphic to the space of rapidly decreasing sequences. Using this, it would be relatively easy to prove that $C^\infty(\mathbb R)\cong(C^\infty([0,1]))^{\kern.7mm\mathbb N_0}$. However, a direct proof of (*) is not very simple, (cont.)

Comment: and I am interested to know whether using ($*$) could be replaced by a simpler argument in proving $C^\infty(\mathbb R)\cong(C^\infty([0,1]))^{\kern.4mm\mathbb N_0}$.